# How to deal with my current employer finding out about my application to immigrate to Canada?

Tags: termination, visa

The Canadian immigration officials apparently verify work experience by contacting my current employer. No one at my workplace knows about my application. I fear that I may lose my job or face other consequences when they find out. What can I do to avoid problems at my current workplace due to such visits or inquiries by the immigration officials?

Comment: I understand why OP added [tag:visa] and [tag:termination], but I am not sure these are relevant. I did not remove it during my edit though, since I am 50-50 on this. This question might also need some other tags, but I am not sure what those would be. If someone else thinks likewise and has better ideas, please edit the tags.

Comment: don't see anything wrong with the tags. A little nitpicky to me.

Answer (score 8):

**TLDR** Don't worry about things that you cannot control, focus on how best you can execute *your* plans, doing your best to avoid burning bridges.

You have already applied for immigration to Canada. The immigration officers *will* contact your employers, you cannot "prevent" it (unless, of course, you withdraw your application, which you clearly won't). You know that you have to resign from your current job at some point. You seem to be worried that your employer might fire you while your application is still being processed, leaving you out of job for a while.

It is best that you let your employer know rather than wait for them to find out from the immigration officials. There's no use trying to "hide" it from them, they will find out anyway, as you have already realized. Tell them that you are planning to immigrate because life your priorities have changed, not because you want to "run away" from your current job, and assure them that you will continue to work to the best of your abilities until you are employed with them. (and then, do what you say!)

Most companies would have no problem with employees departing provided the employees deal with the departure professionally. If they get "offended" and fire you right away, then you have done everything you could to avoid burning the bridge, *they* burned the bridge by being unreasonable. There's nothing much you could do about it (unless your local laws say otherwise). Accept it as a part of life and move on.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the person contacting your employer won't tell them exactly *why* they need to verify your employment. Chances are the person making the call won't even know why; they just have a list of verification calls to get through. I'm sure there are other reasons why Canadian immigration might want to verify someone's employment. It could be a relative who wants to emigrate, or is in legal trouble there, or something like that. I wouldn't lie, though. If your boss does ask about it, I'd say something vague like "it's some family stuff".

I'm assuming you're going to do the right thing and give your employer the proper notice. When you do give notice, try to make the transition as smooth as possible. I don't think you owe them any more than that.